# Nginx reverse proxy configuration for cadvisor

Tags: nginx

I am trying to configure nginx to proxy to a cadvisor docker instance running on host port 8000.

I have the following configuration:

```
upstream cadvisor {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}
...
...
server {
    ...
    ...
    location /cadvisor {
        rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
        rewrite ^/cadvisor$ /cadvisor/ permanent;
        rewrite ^/cadvisor(/.*) $1 break;
        auth_basic "Restricted"; #For Basic Auth
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd; #For Basic Auth
        proxy_pass http://cadvisor;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect ~^/(.*)/ /cadvisor/$1;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

This works for all URLs except for the following (which is one of the links cadvisor generates) https://myserver.com/cadvisor/containers//docker/a11c7edcc131d92c6ec3476329e5a54c82d2c31ee3f5592ba3fcb9386cb4f06a

This is probably because the double slashes before 'docker' in the URL messes up css path. My problem would be solved if I could redirect these URLs to single slash version of the url (i.e. https://myserver.com/cadvisor/containers/docker/a11c7edcc131d92c6ec3476329e5a54c82d2c31ee3f5592ba3fcb9386cb4f06a)

Is there any way to redirect the URL to a single slash version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rewrite` directive seems to operate on a normalised version of the URI which does not see sequences of double `/`. It is possible to correct your double `/` situation by operating on the `$request_uri` variable instead:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)//(.*)$) { return 302 $1/$2; }
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) regarding the `if` directive.